# Yaw error calculation for a wind turbine using matlab

Tags: matlab, validation, for-loop

We know theoretically that

yaw error =  wind direction - nacelle direction

After I have wind direction and nacelle direction data sets and hence calculated yaw error using above formula. I have calculated the absolute value of yaw error. Once I calculated the yaw error values I found that this calculation is not correct and hence I have to modify further with this formula

```
     Error = 360 - yaw error
```

So basically I have to run a for look which is going to check my each yaw error value and if there is some wrong with that data it must replace with original data.. for example if my yaw error values are 10,20,30,40,300. it seems there is a wrong with 300 value because of quadrant changes hence it would replace with
        error = 360 - 300 = 60. I have written a code for this below :

```
for i = 1:yaw error

    if yaw_error > 180

          error = 360 -yaw_error

    else

    end

end

yaw error = [yaw error  error];
```

Can you help me where I am wrong ??
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question

lets say x is a matrix of yaw error values

```
x =  [10 20 30 40 190 160 70 120 300 180 30]
```

you find the indices of the values greater than 180

```
z = find(x > 180)
z =

     5     9
```

subtract them from 360

```
>> d =360 - x(z)


d =

   170    60
```

and place them back in the orignal matrix

```
>> x(z) = d

x =


x =

    10    20    30    40   170   160    70   120    60   180    30
```

**One-liner would be** 
`x(find(x > 180)) = 360 - x(find(x > 180))` or `x(x>180)=360-x(x>180)`

Comment: You can omit the  `find` command and just to `x(x>180)=360-x(x>180)`

Answer (score 1):

The one-liner of Umar is correct and elegant.

For your understanding, I have debuged your original code to:

```
yaw_error = [ 10,20,30,40,300]

for i = 1:numel(yaw_error)
    if yaw_error(i) > 180
      yaw_error(i) = 360 -yaw_error(i);
    end
end;

yaw_error
```